# Express js require() followed by funtion(app)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Im fairly new to Nodejs and express, I was looking through some tutorials and examples and stumbled across

this inside app.js
var router = require('./router')(app);

What is the purpose of doing this?

This is whats inside the router file

```
module.exports = function (app) {
  // The signup route
  app.use('/signup', require('./routes/signup'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You import your routers from another file.
This is a technique for scaffolding. Models, views, controllers and routers are kept in different files and then you import them into a `main.js` with `require()`.

You create your project modular, it's more easy to scale and develop with team.

Answer (score 0):

This is a popular modular pattern in javascript, often seen in node. Here's what you gain:

1. You can modularize your code into separate files so you don't end up with big monolith chunks of code.
2. By requiring the module as a function, you can pass some variable constants (such as the application config, or a datatbase entry point).
3. You can choose what to expose, and what to keep private by using `module.exports` which cleans up the global object for the application.

In the code snippet you provided, your passing the app config to the routes file, where you are creating a route that is reliant on the variable. If that route relied on interior logic, that logic could be scoped to the routes.js file rather than be exposed to the rest of the application.